# Android calling API from my app very slow using cellular network

Tags: android

We have very strange issue.

We are using godaddy domain and google cloud for hosting.

We have App on Android and iOS everything seems working fine.

But Android app taking 40 second to call API. As server log showing request served in 100ms.

This happens with particular when we are on cellular data. All other websites loading fast.

Issue happen Android app + Idea cellular only.

When we hit same API URL on mobile browser it works normal. But in app it takes 40sec to 4 min to get response.

In ios app we are not facing this issue with idea cellular network.

We are unable to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi, i am facing same issue with JIO, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

check if the cellular is consuming any proxy. if so disable it and try again. if the problem persists then use cloud flare or google DNS. I hope it will help you out.

Comment: To be more clear in same device and cellular network. When you call API from mobile browser it works well but when we call through android app the problem happen.